# Sort pairs alphabetically in Bash

Tags: bash, sorting, sed, awk

I have a file with the following data in it:

```
adam
humanities

castiel
sciences

antwon
sciences

dmitri
informatics

zoe
mathematics

bernard
economics
```

I want to be able to sort the file w.r.t the names of the people so that the output looks like so:

```
adam
humanities

antwon
sciences

bernard
economics

castiel
sciences

dmitri
informatics

zoe
mathematics
```

`cat filename | sort` sorts all the data including the subjects. How do I sort it with the names of people?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using **asorti** in **awk** to **sort** the array of data

```
awk '{a[$1]=$2} END {n=asorti(a,c);for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print c[i] "\n" a[c[i]] "\n"}' RS= file
adam
humanities

antwon
sciences

bernard
economics

castiel
sciences

dmitri
informatics

zoe
mathematics
```

If your **awk** does not have **asorti**, try this:

```
awk '{print $1,$2}' RS="" file | sort | awk '{print $1 "\n" $2 "\n"}'
```

Comment: +1 Note that `asorti` is part of gawk (GNU awk). So it may not be available on all systems.

Comment: I ended up using the external sort as this would have to be run on more than one server and i really am not sure if gawk would be available in all of them. Thanks, Jotne!!

Answer (score 2):

It is a quite brutal solution, but works... :) You can make it look better.
The main idea is to create

```
<name>|<occupation>\n
```

list, and sort it than make it look as the original.

```
cat /tmp/delme | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/|/g' | sed -e 's/||/\n|/g' | sort | sed -e 's/|/\n/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use awk - strip the empty lines and print each record separated by colon say. Then sort and then using awk print the record in the required format.

```
awk -v RS="" -F"\n" '{print $1 ":" $2}' e | sort | awk -v FS=":" '{print $1 "\n" $2 "\n"}'
```

Comment: +1 for awk and adding `-F'\n'` option to the first awk should allow for spaces in both name and subject field.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/./!d;$!N;s/\n/ /' file | sort | sed 's/ /\n/g;$!G'
```

Drop blank lines. Read two lines into the pattern space. Replace newline with space. Sort file. The replace the newlines and add in blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty and won't work if your names contain spaces...you probably want a `perl` solution to do this in a sane and readable way.

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\n' '{ print $1, $2 }' foo.input | sort | sed -e 's#$#\n#g' -e 's# #\n#g'
adam
humanities

antwon
sciences

bernard
economics

castiel
sciences

dmitri
informatics

zoe
mathematics
```