# Bash - Replace one string in one with another string from another file

Tags: regex, replace, sed, awk

I have two sorted text files. File A's data looks like this:

```
adam
humanities

antwon
sciences

bernard
economics

castiel
sciences

dmitri
informatics

zoe
mathematics
```

File B's data looks like this:

```
adamburnston
antwonreed
justbernard
castiel
dmitrivalchenkov
zoematthews
```

I need to replace the line in file A(adam), with the line in file B(adamburnston). Both the files are alphabetically arranged and contain the same number of entries. How do I achieve this result?

Expected output:

```
adamburnston
humanities

antwonreed
sciences

justbernard
economics

castiel
sciences

dmitrivalchenkov
informatics

zoematthews
mathematics
```

Comment: Your profile says: `learning Python at the moment`.  Why not utilize it?

Comment: @devnull - 'coz I have been asked explicitly to do it in bash. Given a choice, I'd try it in python.

Comment: If you're *asked* to do stuff in bash frequently (as also evident from your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374545/sorting-alphabetically-in-bash) question, why not make an attempt to learn it?

Comment: You want to do it in bash or awk?

Comment: @devnull - Isn't asking questions part of learning?

Comment: Moreover, as a `Sysadmin leaning towards *nix` (again from your profile), you should have a basic understanding of shell commands.

Comment: Asking questions is indeed a part of learning. Asking others to write it for you is not. You have to give it a try, then come back with the code you attempted and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: `Isn't asking questions part of learning?`  Yes, but you need to be aware of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following pipeline works:

```
sed '2~3!d' A | paste -d $'\n' B - | sed $'3~2i\n'
```

The first part tells GNU sed to print the second line, and then each third line. `paste` merges B with the output of the first sed, using a newline as the delimiter. The last line adds newlines after each pair of lines.

Answer (score 2):

This awk should work:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[i++]=$0;next} NF>0{c++; if (c%2==0) print a[j++] ORS $0 ORS}' fileB fileA
```